# Tutorial on how to set up a very simple J2EE web application from scratch?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I was wondering where I can find a web tutorial or book to show me how to set up a Java web App J2EE from scratch? Which starts from showing you what you need to install and how, To getting a server up and a Hello world on the browser?

I would rather not to use a framework such as spring or grails because I want to understand how it actually works at a Java level.

I have been using RoR for the last 2 years and I got a job as a trainee Java developer and would just like to get a better idea of how everything works, the architecture etc.

Many thanks.

Comment: I trust you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75064/beginning-j2ee)?

Comment: Java EE contains many APIs. Do you need servlets and JSPs? EJBs? JNDI? JDBC? JMS? JTA? JPA?

Comment: @JB Nizer: Although OP did mention J2EE he also did mention *"web application"* and *"very simple"* as well as *"Hello world"*.  I'm somehow willing to bet that starting with a simple *.war* containing some "Hello, world!" servlet followed by another "Hello, world!" *.jsp* would be a good start ; )

Comment: This question is too broad and not constructive. I suggest to start at our tag wiki pages: [JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) and [Servlets](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Comment: Try this: www.centerkey.com/jboss/

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to understand at Java Level? Well you need to know many things before:
If you want to learn J2EE specification try [the JavaEE Sun (Nows Oracle) Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/). 
It is a large one, but it is perfect if you want to know the JavaEE specification. You don't want to learn Spring yet, but Spring is just a framework to replace the normal JavaEE provided by Oracle.

But like JB Nizet said. There are a lot of APIs. 
JSP - Java Server Pages for the web layer.
EJB - A solution for the business layer.
JNDI - A directory tree to put and search for objects.
JDBC - This is an important one, With JDBC you can interact with database. 
JMS - You can send messages to other java applications in a async way. This is a really good designed API.
JTA - An api to manage transactions. 
JPA - It is an ORM, Hibernate follows this API.

Try to learn design patterns to. They are very useful and important.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to get Maven installed in your development machine, get the m2e Maven plugin installed in your eclipse, create a new Maven project, search for a jboss javaEE 6 archetype (one that deploys to a jboss as) or an appfuse archetype (they have ready made archetypes that deploy well to many application servers or servlet containers using Cargo plugin).

This will see you through for a long time.