# Design Web application

Tags: java

I want to build a java web application and I don't have any background how to do that.
Can you plz tell me what is the starting point to do that and where can I found useful open source codes that I can use them to design my web application.

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/ is a good starter resource for the browser-related part, the rest depends on your task.

Comment: If you have no idea how to build a java web app, why do you want to do it?  If you want to learn, do a web search - there are more than enough learning sources available.  Start here, for example: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/tools/webapps_1/

Comment: I think the question is too general. If you're totally new (and don't even know what ot ask for) I'll suggest you to look at [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/). It'll provide you full stack to create web application in java language.

Comment: This question has been asked time and time again. I suggest you do a search for "Java web application tutorial". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122313/looking-for-a-java-server-tutorial http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057718/java-jsp-tutorial http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327948/tutorial-on-how-to-set-up-a-very-simple-j2ee-web-application-from-scratch

Answer (score 1):

There are many different frameworks and without more information it's difficult to know what would suit you.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#Java is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You have to know concepts such as Servlet, Servlet Container, Application Server(such as Apache tomcat) and little information about Html.
Exist several book for this goal, my opinion is : you start by a book related to Jsp/Servlet concept, these books good explained.

Comment: Agreed [Head First Design Servlets](http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Servlets-JSP-Certified/dp/0596516681) I would recommend.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/WebApp.html) you can learn how java web applications work and [here](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/html/jspbasics.fm1.html) is a very basic java web application example to get you started. I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the Java EE tutorial, its [Web Tier part](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/geysj.html). I think it's the fastest way to get knowledge that would allow you to understand the base concepts...

Answer (score 0):

The **minimal structure of a web application** is the following:

- /WEB-INF

  - /classes - stores the compiled Java classes your webapp uses
  - /lib - contains the additional libraries your webapp may need to run
  - web.xml - key file in every webapp; explained below
- web files and folders (HTML/JSP/CSS/Javascript)

You may want to start out with **Eclipse for Java-EE**, since it automatically creates the webapp structure for you, so it's the perfect place to start learning, in my opinion; you can find it [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr1).

After you install, the **basic steps** to create your web application are:

- Create your project by accessing **File > New > Dynamic Web Project**.
- Name your project, click Next, Next and check the **Generate deployment descriptor** checkbox. Now hit Finish.

Now that the structure is created, your **main points of interest** will be:

- **Deployment Descriptor** - Is an overview of your web.xml file. Here you can declare all your servlets and their URL paths, you can point to specific error pages triggered by specific codes (e.g 404, 500) or exceptions that occur in your Java/JSP code (e.g NullPointerException, FileNotFoundException), plus do many other things to enhance your webapp. You can trigger between text and graphical XML editing in the bottom-left of the code window.
- **Java Resources** - Here you define your Java classes and servlets. The main role of a Java class in a webapp will be to collect and process data. For example you can define your own math class that exposes methods which do basic calculations. A servlet will usually call one of these classes and output the result to the response output stream. Be sure to provide a solid project structure with the help of packages.
- **WebContent** - this will contain all the web pages your webapp will show, including scripts, images and stylesheets. You are free to create your own folder structure in this section.

Some useful **tutorials** to get you started:

- [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/)
- [JSP](http://www.jsptut.com/)
- [Servlets, Server setup](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/)
- [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)

Once you're done with your webapp, you can either **Run it on a server** directly from Eclipse, or you can **export it as a WAR file** and deploy it on the server of choice, which is usually done by copying the WAR file in the webapps folder.

Finally, try to **experiment** with all the webapp features Eclipse exposes to you. Good luck!